# How to split single Cat 6 with POE to Cat 6 data only and data/POE

Tags: wireless-networking, splitter

thanks to anyone that has the time and inclination to read this.  I have a cctv camera in my shed which is powered over cat 6 with poe.  The poe injector is about 15m from the shed in my garage.  Despite having a wireless range extender in my garage my wireless signal in the shed is intermittent.  Is there a way I can use the poe cable in the shed to give me a wireless network too?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you don't have AC power in the shed?

Comment: Yes - the shed has power.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not without an additional power source.

You can treat your POE cable as a regular cable, get a POE switch (or regular switch + poe injector and power the CCTV camera over that.  You could then use another port to set up another access point for your garage.

If you don't have power, and running it would be very expensive, you could probably do this with a solar panel, battery and inverter for < US$300 (depending on where you live etc).  You might not even need an inverter (but will want something else) if your AP and CCTV camera can work on <= 12 volts.

Comment: Thanks.  My garage has the poe switch that powers two cameras one of which is in my shed.  The poe switch connects to a wireless range extender.  Having done some research this evening I've seen a NETGEAR ProSAFE GS105PE 5 which provides pass through poe.  Unless I've missed a trick this would be useful as it doesn't require AC and I could then connect to a spare wireless router (using only one AC socket) giving me good wireless network coverage in and around the shed.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue.  I was able to use a poe powered pass through switch.  This is poe powered only but also shares the poe with 2 other poe powered devices (subject to maximum power requirements).  It also provides 2 normal ports.  I connected the poe cable coming in to my shed to the switch, connected my camera to one of the poe out ports and connected a wireless access point to one of the normal ports.  I now have great wireless in the shed and around the garden and the camera works as it did before.  The only slightly down side is that my access point requires an AC socket which limits where you put it.  Eventually I'll invest in a poe powered AP.